sql in excel vba - child parent subquery
I am trying to select only rows from the INPUT table which do not have a child  - in SQL.The result is in OUTPUT.  To make it easier, for now, I am considering only the columns 5H and 6H (the other columns I will do later after I have figured how the code needs to be written).
The first part of the code before UNION - inserts only rows which have all columns - 1H thru 6H. Then the second part, after UNION, should make sure that only the columns where 5H is not NULL and 6H is null and which do not have a child in 6H, will be included. But it does not work. (NAME5 appears in the OUTPUT - but NAME5 is a parent for the child NAME6).
The embedded JOIN has this:  WHERE v1.[5H] <> v2.[5H] -- to make sure that the row which is a parent will be excluded (i.e. v1.[5H] already exists in OUTPUT for a child row). But something goes wrong. Any idea why? Thank you for your help.
I am working in Excel - vba. I was having problems to copy the code in a readable format - hence I am enclosing the code as a picture as well
What I do not understand,
why the issue is with: NAME5 is in output and it should not be there, because its child NAME6 is in OUTPUT.
But here it works: the child NAME17 is in OUTPUT but its parent NAME16 is not in the OUTPUT (which is correct).
Or NAME2 and NAME3 ... it is correct
the code is:
SQLQuery = _  
"SELECT  v1.[name], v1.[1H], v1.[2H], v1.[3H], v1.[4H], v1.[5H], v1.[6H]" & _
    " FROM [INPUT$] as v1 WHERE  v1.[2H] IS NOT NULL and " & _
    " v1.[3H] IS NOT NULL AND v1.[4H] IS NOT NULL AND v1.[5H] IS NOT NULL AND v1.[6H] IS NOT NULL " & _
"UNION " & _
"SELECT DISTINCT  v1.[name], v1.[1H], v1.[2H], v1.[3H], v1.[4H], v1.[5H], v1.[6H]" & _
    " FROM [INPUT$] as v1  " & _
    " INNER JOIN  " & _
    " (SELECT  * " & _
        " FROM [INPUT$] WHERE [5H] IS NOT NULL AND  [6H] IS NULL )  as v2  " & _
        " ON v1.[1H] = v2.[1H] and v1.[2H] = v2.[2H] and v1.[3H] = v2.[3H] and v1.[4H] = v2.[4H]  " & _
        " WHERE v1.[5H] <> v2.[5H]  "





Here is a SQL-Server fiddle that examins the source for the record with name=NAME5  https://dbfiddle.uk/4gIH98Tr

For 'NAME22'  - possible this row do not have childs?

name22 - will go to the OUTPUT as well. But this is in 4H (currently I am solving the issue for 5H and 6H) - when the code is clear here, certainly, NAME22 (column 4H)  and other columns towards V1 will be included in the code

The record with name=Name5 is included because the 2nd query (after the union) allows it.
...    
UNION
    "SELECT DISTINCT  v1.[name], v1.[1H], v1.[2H], v1.[3H], v1.[4H], v1.[5H], v1.[6H]" & _
        " FROM [INPUT$] as v1  " & _
        " INNER JOIN  " & _
        " (SELECT  * " & _
            " FROM [INPUT$] WHERE [5H] IS NOT NULL AND  [6H] IS NULL )  as v2  " & _
            " ON v1.[1H] = v2.[1H] and v1.[2H] = v2.[2H] and v1.[3H] = v2.[3H] and v1.[4H] = v2.[4H]  " & _
            " WHERE v1.[5H] <> v2.[5H]  "

If you examine the values from v2.5H you can see 3 values that satisfy the join criteria
ON v1.[1H] = v2.[1H] and v1.[2H] = v2.[2H] and v1.[3H] = v2.[3H] and v1.[4H] = v2.[4H]

and WHERE clause.
WHERE v1.[5H] <> v2.[5H]




name
1H
2H
3H
4H
5H
v2.5H
6H




NAME19
1
1
1
2
2
1,3,4
null


NAME20
1
1
1
2
3
1,2,4
null


NAME21
1
1
1
2
4
1,2
null


NAME5
1
1
1
2
1
2,3,4
null


NAME6
1
1
1
2
1
2,3,4
1




Self JOIN source data to find childs for every row.
If row do not have child - this is target row.
There t2 (right side) row is child of t1 (left side) row, if
t1.cname<>t2.cname  -- a row cannot be a parent/child of itself
   and (t1.c1H=t2.c1H or t1.c1H is null) 
   and (t1.c2H=t2.c2H or t1.c2H is null)
   and (t1.c3H=t2.c3H or t1.c3H is null)
   and (t1.c4H=t2.c4H or t1.c4H is null)
   and (t1.c5H=t2.c5H or t1.c5H is null)
   and (t1.c6H=t2.c6H or t1.c6H is null)

There
value of child is equal to parent or parent is null
for example:
(1,1) is child of (1,null)
(1,1,2) is child of (1,1,null)
(1,1,2) is not child of (1,1,1)
When obviously    (1,1,1,1,1,1) is child of (1,1,1,1,1,null)
Note:
(1,1,1,1,1,1) is child of (1,1,1,1,1,1) - we cannot distinguish who is the parent, who is the child.
(1,1,1,1,1,null) is child of (1,1,1,1,1,null)
If you have those cases check additionally.
See example



cname
c1H
c2H
c3H
c4H
c5H
c6H
comment




name1
1
1
1
1
null
null
no


name2
1
1
1
1
1
null
no


name3
1
1
1
1
1
1
yes


name4
1
1
1
2
null
null
no


name5
1
1
1
2
1
null
no


name6
1
1
1
2
1
1
yes


name19
1
1
1
2
2
null
yes


name20
1
1
1
2
3
null
yes


name21
1
1
1
2
4
null
yes


name22
1
1
1
3
null
null
no/yes?


name7
1
1
1
null
null
null
no


name8
1
1
2
null
null
null
no


name9
1
1
2
1
null
null
no


name10
1
1
2
1
1
null
no


name11
1
1
2
1
1
1
yes


name12
1
1
null
null
null
null
no


name13
1
2
null
null
null
null
no


name14
1
2
1
null
null
null
no


name15
1
2
1
1
null
null
no


name16
1
2
1
1
1
null
no


name17
1
2
1
1
1
1
yes


name18
1
null
null
null
null
null
no



Query
select *
from test t1
left join test t2 
  on  t1.cname<>t2.cname 
   and (t1.c1H=t2.c1H or t1.c1H is null)
   and (t1.c2H=t2.c2H or t1.c2H is null)
   and (t1.c3H=t2.c3H or t1.c3H is null)
   and (t1.c4H=t2.c4H or t1.c4H is null)
   and (t1.c5H=t2.c5H or t1.c5H is null)
   and (t1.c6H=t2.c6H or t1.c6H is null)
where t2.cname is null  -- no childs

Output



cname
c1H
c2H
c3H
c4H
c5H
c6H
comment




name3
1
1
1
1
1
1
yes


name6
1
1
1
2
1
1
yes


name19
1
1
1
2
2
null
yes


name20
1
1
1
2
3
null
yes


name21
1
1
1
2
4
null
yes


name22
1
1
1
3
null
null
no/yes?


name11
1
1
2
1
1
1
yes


name17
1
2
1
1
1
1
yes



For 'name22' in your data, I think this is target row.
Update1. This is solution for all columns, not only 5 and 6.
fiddle
